# Number of fixed points in a fixed point iteration function

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, linear-approximation

I'm trying to understand if a fixed point iteration function can have more than 1 fixed points.

In theory I tried to find an f(x) such that I could generate an iteration function g(x) in a way that g(x) has multiple fixed points but I kinda got stuck on this, which got me thinking that maybe there is only one fixed point.

Maybe someone could offer an example or an explanation as to how many fixed points could be?
thanks

Comment: Try investigating something like $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ using the real cube root.  Or for a more extreme case try $g(x)=x$

Comment: I suggest that you define your terms, and explain the "kinda got stuck on this" in detail.

Comment: If you want something visual, look up Newton fractals, these depict the convergence of Newton's method for polynomials. Newton's method is a fixed-point iteration, and the roots of the polynomial are fixed points, obviously more than one. The regions that belong to one root, the Fatou sets, share a fractal boundary, the Julia set for this rational iteration.

Comment: Draw the line $y=x$, then draw a line ($y=g(x)$) that crosses it multiple times. Every intersection is a fixed point of $g$.